# Difference between X,Y and Latitude,Longitude or Meters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, latitude-longitude, wgs84

According to Esri:

> "To add a table of x,y coordinates to your map, the table must contain
> two fields: one for the x-coordinate and one for the y-coordinate. The
> values in the fields may represent any coordinate system and units
> such as latitude and longitude or meters."

I am getting confused here.

For example, on GPS what is X,Y and are they different than Latitude,Longitude?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For coordinates captured using a GPS, or by any means, longitude is the X value and latitude is the Y value.  These are for a geographic coordinate system and have units of degrees.

Alternatively your GPS may be set to return values for eastings and northings using a projected coordinate system with units often in meters (can be feet, etc).